# Reading asynchronously from either stdout or stderr

Tags: c#, process, io, stdout, stderr

In my program I spawn a process and then read its standard output one character at a time as follows:

```
char[] c = new char[1];
while (true)
{
  await targetProcess.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(c, 0, 1);
  // use c[0] here
}
```

This read is conditional on a number of things (if statements) not show above. Now, in certain situations, what I want to do is read *either* `StandardOutput` *or* `StandardError`, so effectively I want something like

```
async Task ReadFromRightStream()
{
  if (targetProcess.StandardError.Peek() != -1)
    await targetProcess.StandardError.ReadAsync(c, 0, 1);
  else await targetProcess.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(c, 0, 1);
}
```

But the above code simply blocks on `Peek()`. Ideally, I would like to merge both streams into a single stream and then `ReadAsync()` on that.

Note: I cannot use process events because I need one character at a time (not the whole string) and the capture is conditional on the input characters.

Comment: Redirect streams and react on `targetProcess.OutputDataReceived` and `targetProcess.ErrorDataReceived`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I need to capture exactly 1 character at a time and the type of capture is conditional on the previously captured data. thus, I cannot unconditionally subscribe to two events.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider redirecting the stdout and stderr. This will fire an event when data is send to either output or error. You also have the ability to use the same method to handle both events.

```
void Method()
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = ...,
        Arguments = ...,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = startInfo
    };

    process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputHandler;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessOutputHandler;

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
}

private void OnProcessOutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    OutputMessage(e.Data);
}
```

Comment: As I mention towards the bottom of my question, subscribing to these events is not a viable option for me. The streams are already redirected, but I need to read the characters one by one.

Comment: I missed that last remark, sorry. To bad, it is a great way to capture the output.